# Insert two values in a pandas dataframe from an array in specifik columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and an array. The array has two values and I would like to insert the values from the array in the dataframe. I want to insert the array values on index '2020-12-31' and columns 'v2' and 'v3' (so I want to replace 300 with 305 and 250 with 255).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df=pd.DataFrame({'v0': [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
    'v1': [600, 550, 600, 600, 600, 600, 550, 500, 450, 350, np.NaN, np.NaN],
                      'v2': [350, 400, 450, 500, 450, 400, 450, 400, 350, 300, np.NaN, np.NaN],
                      'v3': [350, 350, 450, 500, 450, 400, 400, 300, 300, 250, np.NaN, np.NaN]},
                     index=pd.date_range('2020-03-31', '2021-02-28', freq='M'))

array=np.array([305, 255])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with list of columns names, it working because same length like array:

```
df.loc['2020-12-31', ['v2','v3']] = array
print (df)
            v0     v1     v2     v3
2020-03-31   3  600.0  350.0  350.0
2020-04-30   4  550.0  400.0  350.0
2020-05-31   5  600.0  450.0  450.0
2020-06-30   6  600.0  500.0  500.0
2020-07-31   7  600.0  450.0  450.0
2020-08-31   8  600.0  400.0  400.0
2020-09-30   9  550.0  450.0  400.0
2020-10-31  10  500.0  400.0  300.0
2020-11-30  11  450.0  350.0  300.0
2020-12-31  12  350.0  305.0  255.0
2021-01-31  13    NaN    NaN    NaN
2021-02-28  14    NaN    NaN    NaN
```